# Modifying self in `iter_mut().map(..)`, aka mutable functional collection operations

Tags: iterator, rust

How do I convert something like this:

```
let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4i32];
for i in a.iter_mut() {
    *i += 1;
}
```

to a one line operation using `map` and a closure?

I tried:

```
a.iter_mut().map(|i| *i + 1).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

The above only works if I reassign it to `a`. Why is this? Is `map` getting a copy of `a` instead of a mutable reference? If so, how can I get a mutable reference?

Comment: "mutable" and "functional" are two words that I don't see together very often. Mutating a variable is a side-effect, something that a lot of functional programming strives to minimize.

Comment: `.map()` doesn’t modify things in place; it returns a new iterator. There isn’t any mutable version of it. You can still convert that to a one-line operation, though: `for i in a.iter_mut() { *i += 1; }`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code dereferences the variable (`*i`) then adds one to it. Nowhere in there does the *original value* get changed.

The best way to do what you asked is to use [`Iterator::for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each):

```
a.iter_mut().for_each(|i| *i += 1);
```

This gets an iterator of mutable references to the numbers in your vector. For each item, it dereferences the reference and then increments it.

You could use `map` and `collect`, but doing so is non-idiomatic and potentially wasteful. This uses `map` for the side-effect of mutating the *original value*. The "return value" of assignment is the unit type `()` - an empty tuple. We use `collect::<Vec<()>>` to force the Iterator adapter to iterate. This last bit `::<...>` is called the *turbofish* and allows us to provide a *type parameter* to the `collect` call, informing it what type to use, as nothing else would constrain the return type.:

```
let _ = a.iter_mut().map(|i| *i += 1).collect::<Vec<()>>();
```

You could also use something like [`Iterator::count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count), which is lighter than creating a `Vec`, but still ultimately unneeded:

```
a.iter_mut().map(|i| *i += 1).count();
```

As [Ry- says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651259/modifying-self-in-iter-mut-map-aka-mutable-functional-collection-operat#comment45600111_28651259), using a `for` loop is more idiomatic:

```
for i in &mut a {
    *i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some of the details.

Is there a way to pass a closure to `iter_mut`?

Comment: Instead of comparing it to `map!`, which only exists for Ruby's Array and Set classes, `map` is more like `Enumerable#map`.

Comment: There is no way to pass a closure directly to `iter_mut`; Rust's iterator adapters are more orthoganally factored than that. However, the compiler's optimizations generally make up for performance losses you might be worried about.

Comment: You should use `.count()` to "run" the iterator chain, and then it's not a ridiculously bad idea any more, just weird style.